# Vlc In Windows Forms (C++/Cli)

Tags: .net, winforms, media-player, vlc, libvlc

I am using [LibVlc.Net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libvlcnet/files/libvlcnet/libvlcnet-0.3.1.0/) to embed Vlc in winforms using C++/Cli.
Dragged a 'VlcPlayerControl' Component from ToolBox to winforms UI  
Followed [this](http://vlcvbnet.proboards.com/thread/1/wrapper-vlc-vb-net?page=1&scrollTo=9) tutorial. 
 There are no Build errors,
but i see a run time error when i click on Play button

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in dz.mediaplayer.vlc.dll
>
> Additional information: Package file not found.

here's my code for button_click event. Error occurs at line 2 in code below

```
vlcPlayerControl1->Initialize();
DZ::MediaPlayer::Io::MediaInput^ Mi = gcnew DZ::MediaPlayer::Io::MediaInput(DZ::MediaPlayer::Io::MediaInputType::File, "D://video.mp4");
vlcPlayerControl1->Play(Mi);
```

File path is correct, i have video.mp4 in D drive
What Could be the issue?
Thanks